# stopListening to Mojo.Event

Tags: javascript, prototype, webos

I have several event listeners in a webOS app and each one I set up like this:

```
this.controller.listen(
    'aWidget', 
    Mojo.Event.widgetEvent, 
    this.respondToWidgetEvent.bindAsEventListener(this)
);
```

And to stop listening I write code like this:

```
this.controller.stopListening(
    'aWidget', 
    Mojo.Event.widgetEvent, 
    this.respondToWidgetEvent.bindAsEventListener(this)
);
```

However, I realize now that my listeners may not be stopping.  When I call `bindAsEventListener` on a function, do I get back the same object each time?  If not, does `stopListening` make sure to remove the appropriate listener anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly each call to bindAsEventListener() returns a new instance.  Prevent that action by calling it once and setting a var:

```
bindToWidget = this.respondToWidgetEvent.bindAsEventListener(this);

this.controller.listen(
    'aWidget', 
    Mojo.Event.widgetEvent, 
    bindToWidget
);

this.controller.stopListening(
    'aWidget', 
    Mojo.Event.widgetEvent, 
    bindToWidget
);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected that was the case, since I've seen that pattern in some people's code before, but I've also seen it done the way I did it.  Now I have confirmation that the other pattern with the extra variable was right.